# Matching phrases with R - text mining

Tags: arrays, r, string, text, text-mining

My question is simple to ask, but i think hard to solve. 
I just want to match 2 names of a store:

```
library(stringdist)

a=c("Adidas", "macys","apple store", "VANS Store New York", "new wave","adsasds") 

distances = stringdist("ADIDAS STORE", a, method = 'jw')
res = data.frame(distances, a)
View(res)
```

Answerset:

- 0.4853801 VANS Store New York
- 0.5833333 Adidas
- 0.5972222 new wave
- 0.6085859 apple store
- 1.0000000 macys
- 1.0000000 adsasds

Trying with another methods,I get different results but none good. I only want to know that "ADIDAS STORE" is the same place that "Adidas".

Anyone can help me?

Thank You.

Comment: You also need to handle lower/upper case letters. Try `stringdist("ADIDAS STORE", toupper(a), method = 'jw')` and you will see the difference

Comment: Also I suggest you to grab the best distance you need. I suggest you to read this tutorial, it explains very well the differences between the methods that are implemented in `stringdist` package.

Answer (score 0):

To choose the best distance you can use this code to identify the best  `stringdist` method in your example.

A function rotating on each `stringdist` method

```
library(stringdist)
string_dist<-function(m,a=c("Adidas", "macys","apple store", "VANS Store New York", "new wave","adsasds") ){
  out<-stringdist(a="ADIDAS STORE",b = toupper(a),method=m)
  return(out)  
}
```

Application on your data

```
out<-lapply(methods,FUN = string_dist)
db<-as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(out), nrow=length(unlist(out[1]))))
colnames(db)<-paste("ADIDAS STORE",methods,sep="-")
store_name<-c("Adidas", "macys","apple store", "VANS Store New York", "new wave","adsasds")
```

Now you can choose the best method (I suggest cosine or jw)

```
db<-cbind(store_name,db)
db
store_name ADIDAS STORE-osa ADIDAS STORE-lv ADIDAS STORE-dl ADIDAS STORE-hamming ADIDAS STORE-lcs ADIDAS STORE-qgram
1              Adidas                6               6               6                  Inf                6                  6
2               macys               10              10              10                  Inf               13                 13
3         apple store                5               5               5                  Inf                9                  9
4 VANS Store New York               14              14              14                  Inf               15                 15
5            new wave               10              10              10                  Inf               16                 14
6             adsasds                7               7               7                  Inf                9                  7
  ADIDAS STORE-cosine ADIDAS STORE-jaccard ADIDAS STORE-jw ADIDAS STORE-soundex
1           0.1801084            0.5555556       0.1666667                    0
2           0.5783630            0.8333333       0.4777778                    1
3           0.3914194            0.3636364       0.3077201                    1
4           0.3625447            0.5000000       0.3040936                    1
5           0.6597931            0.7500000       0.5694444                    1
6           0.1996733            0.6666667       0.2698413                    1
```